# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function error in my python3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to open a file with a button but I get this error message:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function
```

Here's my code:

```py
class Something:
    def load_key(self):
        filename = self.browse_files
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            self.key = f.read()

  
    def browse_files():
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("Text files","*.txt*"),("all files","*.*")))
        return filename


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    WIDTH = 780
    HEIGHT = 520

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
   
        self.button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Load a key",              command=Something.load_key(Something), width=450, height=60)
        self.button2.pack(pady=10, padx=50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `filename = self.browse_files` should be `filename = self.browse_files()` instead.

Comment: Also `command=Something.load_key(Something)` is wrong, you need to use an instance of `Something` to call the function `load_key()` and it should be `command=lambda: somevar.load_key()`.